# Displaying false result, while the query returned true

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, sql-update

I am trying to execute the below code.

Execution gets success, but it is displaying  **sorry, Query could not execute...**

My Codes:

**class.php**

```
public function admin_update($id,$update,$value)
    {
        try{
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE admin SET ".$update."=:_value WHERE Id=:_id");
            $stmt->bindparam(":_value",$value);
            $stmt->bindparam(":_id",$id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**update.php**

```
$id = "1";

if(admin_update($id,"Access","Y"))
        {               
            echo "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "sorry, Query could not execute...";
        }
```

MySQL table is updated, but it does not display **Success**, instead, it displays **sorry, Query could not execute...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the result of [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). Since you are not returning anything, it is by default considered as `null`, hence your `if()` condition is always checking it as `false`, and going to the `else()` part.

```
public function admin_update($id,$update,$value)
    {
        try{
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE admin SET ".$update."=:_value WHERE Id=:_id");
            $stmt->bindparam(":_value",$value);
            $stmt->bindparam(":_id",$id);
            return $stmt->execute(); // return the result of execute
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            return 0; // return 0 in case of failure
        }
    }
```